# How to identify size of a 30 pin SIMM (Atari 1040 STe)

Tags: atari, memory

I have recently acquired an **Atari 1040 STe** with 1MB of RAM.

I read that you can extend its RAM with **30 pin SIMM** up to **4MB**. But it can be done **only** with **256KB** or **1MB** SIMM, and that **2MB, 4MB, 8MB** and **16MB** SIMM **should not be used**.

I have 6 30 pin SIMM but there are no stickers on them that tell me their size.

I have 2 models:

- 4 ones with **9 vertical chips** marked "***OKI Japan, M514100B-70SJ, 40222539A9Z***", and there is written on the back of the modules "***MSC23409B-70DS9 4041001, JAPAN***";
- 2 ones with **3 horizontal chips** marked "***JAPAN A014, 9236 65NT, HM514400AS7***", and there is written on the back of the modules "***HB56G19B-7A, 9242 TT 13***".

I don't want to damage my Atari 1040 STe by using modules with the wrong size, so how can I identify the size of 30 pin SIMM with those informations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To identify SIMM sizes based on chip IDs, search the Internet for the chip IDs to see what each chip is (chip datasheets are a good way to find this out), then multiply the chip capacity by the number of chips.

For example, an M514100D (D probably is a newer version but otherwise compatible with M514100B) is a 4Mbit x 1 fast page mode DRAM chip.  So if you have a module with 9, that is probably a 4Mbit x 9 FPM DRAM module (aka 4MByte with parity).

An HM514400 is a 1Mbit x 4 DRAM, so 3 chips would make 1Mbit x 12, so the module is probably 1MByte with parity (9 bits, leaving 3 bits unused/wasted).

Comment: incidentally, in my experience a module with 3 x4 chips is uncommon due to the wasted bits.  I have seen 2 x4 chips plus 1 x1 chip much more frequently, with the x1 chip sometimes being a different size than the other 2.

but it's not impossible, I imagine in this case Hitachi had tons of x4 chips lying around so it was cheap for them to just use those for the 9th (parity) bit and disregard the 3 extra wasted bits.  if there's another chip on the module it's possible the extra bits are being used to enable some kind of ECC memory.